# Eclipse CDT Content Assist Not Completing Structures

Tags: c, eclipse, struct, eclipse-cdt, content-assist

I previously have used content assist in Eclipse CDT without running into problems. However, with a new project I'm having trouble with content assist suggesting members from a C struct. It's accurately suggesting the structure type, just not the members.

I have content assist set to prioritize parsing-based proposals + parsing-based proposals (Task-Focused). I deselected the other options per other recommendations; doesn't seem like it does anything whether they're selected or not.

Here's the struct that I'm trying to get suggestions for:

```
/**
* HAL DIN voltages
*/
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t din0; ///< din0 voltage
    uint16_t din1; ///< din1 voltage
    uint16_t din2; ///< din2 voltage
    uint16_t din3; ///< din3 voltage
    uint16_t din4; ///< din4 voltage
    uint16_t din5; ///< din5 voltage
    uint16_t din6; ///< din6 voltage
    uint16_t din7; ///< din7 voltage
}sDINVoltage;

sDINVoltage test; // sDINVoltage will get suggested
test.//No members get suggested
```

Is there something I'm possibly missing in how my project indexes things? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was always working! Members seem to only be recommended if they're within a function - for example:

```
sDINVoltage voltages_;
voltages_. // No recommendation 

void test_func(void)
{
    sDINVoltage voltages;
    voltages.// Will get recommendation here
}
```

I was trying to get recommendations outside of a function. :) If someone knows why this happens, it still would be nice to know!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question why you get no recommendations outside a function: It is not allowed to set members of a struct outside a function in that way. Probably that is why Eclipse CDT doesn't even give you a suggestion. For example, this would not be allowed:

```
test.din0 = 2;
```

I tried it myself just now with the following code:

```
/* test.c */
typedef struct
{
  char state1;
} STATE_STR;

STATE_STR state_str;

state_str.state1='c';

void main()
{
}
```

Compiled in cygwin I get this error:

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.exe
test.c:8:10: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 state_str.state1='c';
```

(You could use the following code to initialize your structure:

```
typedef struct
{
  char state1;
} STATE_STR;

STATE_STR state_str = {.state1='c'};

void main()
{
}
```

)